# Find index of lowest unique integer in each line of the file

Tags: haskell

The code below finds the index of the lowest unique integer on each line of the file. The numbering starts at 1, and when there's no unique value, the `0` should be output.

The sample input looks like this:

```
3 3 9 1 6 5 8 1 5 3
9 2 9 9 1 8 8 8 2 1 1
```

And the sample output is this:

```
5
0
```

I wonder if this code can be simplified or made more elegant and idiomatic in any way. It's also interesting to me, could I get by w/o the `IntMap` and solve the problem with i.e. lists beautifully.

```
module Main where

import Prelude hiding (filter)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Data.IntMap (IntMap, alter, empty, filter, findMin, fromList, size)

import System.Environment

counts :: [(Int, Int)] -> IntMap [Int]
counts = foldl f empty
  where f m (i,v) = alter f' v m
          where f' :: Maybe [Int] -> Maybe [Int]
                f' (Just is) = Just (i:is)
                f' (Nothing) = Just [i]

g :: IntMap [Int] -> Int
g a = i
  where rs = filter ((== 1) . length) a
        h m | size m == 0 = fromList [(0, [0])]
            | otherwise = m
        (_, [i]) = findMin $ h rs

minUnique :: [Int] -> Int
minUnique l = g r
  where r = counts (zip [1..] l)

main =
  head <$> getArgs >>= readFile >>=
    putStrLn . unlines . map (show . minUnique . map read . words) . lines
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, your usage of `alter` can easily be replaced by `insertWith`:

```
counts :: [(Int, Int)] -> IntMap [Int]
counts = foldr f empty
  where f (i,v) = insertWith (const (i:)) v [i]
```

You could also use `fromListWith`, which is neater but less efficient due to the need to concatenate lists:

```
counts :: [(Int, Int)] -> IntMap [Int]
counts = fromListWith (flip (++)) . map (\(i,v) -> (v,[i]))
```

Second, you could shorten `g` quite a bit as well using a view:

```
g a = case minView $ filter ((== 1) . length) a of
        Nothing      -> 0
        Just ([i],_) -> i
```

Which is also probably slightly less efficient, as it will construct at least a thunk for the rest of the `IntMap`.

Concerning different approaches - you could make a recursive function that removes all duplicates:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

dedup :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
dedup [] = []
dedup ((i,v):ps)
  | null dups = (i,v):dedup ps
  | otherwise = dedup ndups
  where (dups, ndups) = partition ((==v) . snd) ps

minUnique :: [Int] -> Int
minUnique l
  | null ddups = 0
  | otherwise  = fst $ minimumBy (comparing snd) $ ddups
  where ddups = dedup $ zip [1..] l
```

Once more this trades for a bit of efficiency, as the traversal in `partition` makes it O(n²). Not sure whether that can be helped though without involving more complex data structures.